# Is there a term for this?

Tags: phrase-request

In the movie *Monsters Inc.* there is this conversation between Randall and Wazowski:

> Randall: Sh sh sh! You hear that? It's the winds of change.
>   Wazowski: **You hear that? It's the winds of ch...** what a creep.
>   Wazowski: One of these days I am really gonna let you teach that guy a lesson.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3ojN4YpNS4)

The highlighted part is when Wazowski imitated Randall by using a funny voice. My question is: Is there a term for this kind of action?
I tried to find the answer myself but I don't even know what to search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is:

[***mimic***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mimic) : *To copy or imitate so as to ridicule; mock*

Wazowski was *mimicking* Randall.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, the verb 'mock' comes to mind.

> Wazowski was **mocking** Randall by mimicking him.

In this sentence, ['**mocking**'](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=definition%3a%20mock&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) is the overall effect that Wazowski achieved through the act of ['**mimicking**'](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=definition%3a%20mock&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=definition%3a%20mimic&rls=en) Randall.

Mimicking can be done for reasons other than mocking (though infrequent,) and mocking can be done through other means than mimicking.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The reason I answered with *mimic* is that OP asked about "imitating using a funny voice."   If OP had asked about, "making fun of some one by imitating their voice" then, I agree, the answer would be *mock*.